# How do I use AFAssistantPane?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I have searched my entire Mac for `ibplugin` to find the QTKit IBPlugin, but I also came accros a plugin which adds `AFAssistantPane` to IB. I did a Google-search but Google has no results for it. So, does anyone know how I can use this `AFAssistantPane`?

[alt text http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/7963/schermafbeelding2010052.png](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/7963/schermafbeelding2010052.png)

Thanks

---

**Update:** I noted that this is in a private framework (that's why it is not documented).
**Update:** The framework doesn't include header files. Must I hack it and recreate the header files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command line utility for exploration of private frameworks called `class-dump`. You can google for it. Here's the first result that came up for me: [Dumping the iPhone 2.2 Frameworks](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=1083881&p=19848505).

Comment: Awesome thanks! I did `class-dump assistant >> ~/Desktop/Assitant.h` and it has some very nice methods. Cheers!